# Using CSS Grids and @Media Q's making a Mobile 1st website

Tags: html, css, css-grid

So I am making an HTML CSS mockup of my app and I am using CSS grids to show the sponsors what the app would look like, everything is made mobile 1st in mind but when I load it on my desktop, it doesn't show the desktop version it shows the mobile version, but when I use google chromes inspect element tool I can see the Web version and ideas whats wrong?

my file (note its not finished and I know I haven't created the webSide code):

```css
html{
    background-color: deepskyblue;
}

.top{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 4fr 1fr;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.top a {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: white;
}

#top-nav a{
    margin: 25px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-indent: 60px;
    text-align: left;[]
}

#top-nav{
    width: 20%;
    margin-top: -2px;
}

#top-name a, #top-help a{
    font-size: 30px;
}

#top-name{
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 60%;
}

#top-help{
    width: 20%;
    text-align: center;
}

.main-grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: 
        'topApp'
        'appletApps';
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(50px, auto);
}

.menu-grid{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
}

.applet-apps {
    grid-area: appletApps;
}

.top-app {
    grid-area: topApp;
}

.applet img{
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.applet-title h3{
    font-size: 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: orange;
    margin: 0;
}

.applet-title {
    padding: 0px 30px 0px 30px;
    font-size: 65px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: orange;
    margin: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
    
    .menu-grid {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr  1fr 1fr;
    }
    
    .applet-title h3{
        font-size: 40px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 700px) {
    
    .menu-grid {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    }
    
    .applet-title h3{
        font-size: 40px;
    }
    
    #top-nav a{
        font-size: 40px;
        margin: 45px;
    }
    
    #top-name a, #top-help a{
        font-size: 50px;
    }
    
    #top-nav{
        width: 20%;
        float: left;
        margin-top: 3px;
    }
    
    .top {
        padding-bottom: 20px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1025px) {
    
    .main-grid {
        grid-template-areas: 
            'webSide appletApps appletApps appletApps'
            'webSide appletApps appletApps appletApps'
            'webSide appletApps appletApps appletApps';
        grid-auto-rows: minmax(auto, auto);
}
    
    .menu-grid {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    }
    
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    
 <title>App | Canvas</title>
    
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/img/app-icon.png">
    
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:200,400,600" rel="stylesheet">
 
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/animate.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css">
</head>

<body>
    
    <div class="menuPage main-grid">
        <div class="top-app top animated fadeInDown">
            <div id="top-nav">
                <a id="menu-button">&#9776;</a>
            </div>
            <div id="top-name">
                <a>Canvas</a>
            </div>
            <div id="top-help">
                <a>?</a> 
            </div>
        </div> <!-- Top Part of App for Mobile -->
        <div class="applet-apps animated fadeInDown ">
        <div class="applet-title">
            <h3>Favorites</h3>    
        </div>
        <div id="fav" class="menu-grid">
            <div class="applet">
                <img alt="games" src="img/applet-games.png">
            </div>
            <div class="applet">
                <img alt="games" src="img/applet-music.png">
            </div>
            <div class="applet">
                <img alt="games" src="img/applet-meditation.png">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="applet-title">
            <h3>Apps</h3>    
        </div>
        <div id="fav" class="menu-grid">
            <div class="applet">
                <img alt="games" src="img/applet-games.png">
            </div>
            <div class="applet">
                <img alt="games" src="img/applet-games.png">
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- Menu Page -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can your share the desktop resolution?

Comment: 1920 X 1080 , but when I upload to my webhosf and view it on that web address it works